# Python PYPYODBC SQL Server - How to INSERT with IDENTITY_INSERT set to ON

Tags: python, sql-server, pypyodbc

With PYTHON PYPYODBC and SQL SERVER I'm trying to insert rows into a truncated table(truncate code works). I would like to also insert the identity column so I am trying to turn IDENTITY_INSERT to 'ON' and then turn it 'OFF' after the inserted row.

Just successfully did this:

```
 TruncateSQL = "TRUNCATE TABLE [MyTableName]"
 sqlserverCOMMAND = self.sqlserver_cur.execute(TruncateSQL)
 self.sqlserver_conn.commit()
```

Then after I build the INSERT: (INSERT WORKS)

```
 IdentityINSERT_ON_sql = "SET IDENTITY_INSERT [MyTableName] ON"
 IdentityINSERT_OFF_sql = "SET IDENTITY_INSERT [MyTableName] OFF"


 sqlserverCOMMAND = sqlserver_cur.execute(IdentityINSERT_ON_sql)
 sqlserverCOMMAND = sqlserver_cur.execute(INSERTSQL)
 sqlserverCOMMAND = sqlserver_cur.execute(IdentityINSERT_OFF_sql)
 self.sqlserver_conn.commit()
```

I'm not getting an error code, it just hangs Python and I have to restart my computer.
After Python locks-up I've tried to look at the table with a simple SELECT * in TOAD and TOAD hangs.

How can I turn on IDENTITY_INSERT ? (or what am I missing here?)

Comment: I don't think the title of your question and also your question should be _how to SET IDENTITY_INSERT ON_, You just did it, the only thing you have is that python _locks-up_. Are you inserting a large data?

Comment: Just one row with a single INSERT statement.

Comment: Your code looks fine. I agree with @Sami that the hanging issue is probably something else. Please [edit] your question with more details: client OS, SQL Server version, ODBC driver version, connection string, etc..